# Switching Tilde (~) and plus-minus (±) when using an external keyboard over a USB receiver

Tags: keyboard, system-settings, keybindings

I have a MB Pro 2021, with an ISO keyboard layout. I wanted to swap between the  (~) and plus-minus (±) keys. I already tried the option in [Tilde (~) and plus-minus (±) in wrong place on keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/329085/190121), which works for the in-built keyboard, but not for the external keyboard. I have a Logitech MX keys connected via Belkin USB receiver.

I tried setting the hidutil command, by getting the product ID and vendor ID as well, but neither of the options work.

Is there an option to make it work, without using Karabiner or Ukelele?

Comment: This one has me curios…first, I wasn’t aware that Logitech made an ISO keyboard layout.  I don’t have this to test with, but I’m willing to give it a go.  What was the Vendor ID for the Logitech keyboard?  Also, it is safe to assume you’re using a US English layout?

Comment: It should be possible to do using hidutil `--matching` property. What command did you use?