# How switch Mac UK PC keyboard layout backslash \ and backtick ` to match normal UK PC layout

Tags: keyboard

This is the normal UK PC Keyboard Layout:

[image]

We can see the backslash is on the left-bottom corner (right of shift).

But the mac configuration for UK PC layout, the backslash is on the left-top corner (left of the number 1), see the setting as follow:

[image]

So when I use both mac and windows together, this key always confuse me with different output!

UK layout keyboard is ISO standard and the Mac also detects ISO. The only issue is the key on the left of `z` is switched with the key on the left of `1`.

The layout of the UK keyboard:

1. the key on the left of z should be:`\` and `|`
2. the key on the left of 1 should be: `` ` `` and `¬`

But mac switches them.

Comment: Hello Xin, welcome to Ask Different. Yes, the Mac "British - PC" and UK PC keyboard layouts are indeed different, it is described in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#Apple_Macintosh_keyboards, but we can only guess "why" that's the case (only Apple has the answer). I'd recommend that you rewrite your question, otherwise it will probably  be flagged as "primarily opinion-based" and eventually be closed.

Comment: What keyboard do you **actually** have connected? - that makes a difference. Is it an Apple kbd, or a 'windows' one.

Comment: @jaume ok got it. So I will modify the question to how to switch these two keys on Mac to make it same with normal UK PC layout.

Comment: I use Ukelele to make custom keyboard layouts.

Comment: After further experimenting, we need to know not only exactly what keyboard you have connected, but also what OS you're using [& precisely what Mac would be useful additional info]

Comment: For me, adding "British - PC" is the thing that was needed. The keyboard detection wizard never spots this and it's not very obvious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears to be controlled by what you actually have connected... but there is something else going on I'm still trying to hone down.
The best conclusion I can come to at the moment is "it's a bug" but one that seems to be at least partially fixed in High Sierra & Mojave.

This is a UK Apple Keyboard on Mojave [confirmed identical on High Sierrs]

When you first open the panel, it shows as ANSI.

[image]

Press Shift [which I discovered by accident trying to take screenshots] & it changes to ISO.

[image]

Then add British PC & it seems to retain that information...

[image]

Now I've persuaded it to show like that I can't 'break' it again, it seems to stick so far.

---

However, testing on El Capitan, I can't persuade it to flip to ISO, no matter what I do - it stays as ANSI...

[image]

Test on the El Cap machine, swapping a TextEdit document from British to British PC - even though the control panel still claims it's ANSI & after clearing all keyboard prefs & re-detecting the keyboard...

[image]

The Mac 'knows' it's ISO, but won't display as that in the Keyboard Input Sources control panel.

Comment: You have a keyboard with the extra key next to z that El Capitan will not recognize as ISO, even when you use the various remedies in https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html  ?

Comment: Only a tiny number of users have problems with  ISO keyboards, so I don't see how this would be a "bug".

Comment: I've tried 2 different kbds on the El Cap Mac - which is a 10-year-old Mac Pro 3,1. This issue has been there since new & doesn't affect how the connected keyboard actually types, just how it appears in that CP. I've tested it today with its current Logitech UK PC keyboard & also its original Apple wired UK extended. I've tried trashing the kbd plist & regenerating from the setup assistant. No change. In all other respects the machine appears to behave as it ought. Same issue occurs on both High Sierra or Mojave, until you tap the Shift key. I still say 'bug'. Answer edited.

Comment: @Tetsujin my mac version macOS High Sierra version 10.13.4.  what's your mac version? I think you got a right British PC layout with `backslash` next to `Z`. But I still cannot find it

Comment: @Tetsujin  Thanks for clarifying that you do not have a typing problem, just a problem with the display in the preference pane.   But Xin Meng has a typing problem, which is a different animal I think.

Comment: @XinMeng What does your key next to the Z produce when you press it with British PC as the input source?

Comment: @TomGewecke - very possibly. For clarification,  I'm testing on 3 different Macs with 3 different OSes 10.12, 13 & 14beta8. Testing 4 different keyboards, 3 Apple UK extended, wired, 1 Logitech UK-PC wireless. @ Xin - does it make no difference if you tap shift, or the ` key whilst that control panel is open? Also, as Tom says - test what the key actually produces in a text document, as my modified answer above.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I find out an old UK PC Keyboard (Dell) and connect to the mac. After detecting the ISO layout, I go to the keyboard > Input Sources panel, press Ctrl. The layout change. But then I change my new keyboard back (Turtle beach mechanical keyboard), the layout change back! Maybe it is my new keyboard issue. At last the strange thing, after changing back to old Dell keyboard, it is not run detection process and the Change Keyboard Type... button does not work!

Comment: the keys just switch the \  and  `  ,  the key left of Z should be \, but now it is `

Comment: Oh, after installing the Karabiner, I found the keys become right!! The layout in the setting does not change, but these two keys are right. I think maybe when install the Karabiner, it detects the keyboard again and set it to the right layout!

Comment: @XinMeng  Good News.

Comment: I've filed a bug report on Mojave beta so Apple can at least have a look at it & decide whether it's actually a bug or some kind of incompatibility/user error. They'll have a far better chance than me of figuring out what it may be ;) [btw, typo in earlier comment - I'm testing 10.11, 13 & 14b8 not 10.12

Comment: But this bug does not in fact cause a typing problem, right?  The keys produce the right stuff and Keyboard Viewer shows the right stuff?  So the user will not notice anything unless he for some reason looks at this preference pane icon.

Comment: True - but it's still a bug. One I've ignored for years.

Comment: how do you just get your backtick back, not the full switch to pc

Comment: @SuperUberDuper - That's not answerable without considerably more information. Raise it as a new question & link back to this one for context if needed

Answer (score 10):

You need to run the Keyboard Setup Assistant again, and the only reliable way to do that is to delete the files it generated as follows (run this in the terminal):

```
sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboard.plist
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboard.plist
```

Then **restart** your computer. When you log in / plug in the keyboard it should show you the Keyboard Setup Assistant and ask you to press the key to the right of the left shift, i.e. the `\` key on a normal UK keyboard. Do as it asks, and it should detect your keyboard as ISO (*not* ANSI). Accept that, and then make sure in `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources` you are using the `British - PC` layout.

[image: keyboard]

That should give you a normal keyboard layout, with one exception - the `Ctrl` key (the bottom left one) will be mapped to the Mac `Control` key, which you rarely use, and the Windows key will be mapped to `Command`. You probably want to swap those so that copy/paste shortcuts etc. are the same as on Windows.

The easiest way to do that is to install Karabiner-Elements and set it up like this:

[image: karabiner]

Also note that this keyboard layout is not applied before you log in after a reboot, but it *is* applied before you log in after logging out. Very confusing if you have `"` or `@` in your password!

Edit: I have found an easier way to re-run the keyboard detection wizard rather than restarting - change the Country Code in Karabiner-Elements as follows:

[image: country code]

You just need to increment it. The actual value doesn't matter.

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me - I suspect I had originally chosen ansi.

Comment: @Timmmm is it possible to run the keyboard detection again in MacOS 12.0.1? Neither of those files exist for me.

Comment: Yes, I've had continual troubles with this on Mac. It seems to be *very* buggy. The point I've ended up at is: 1. Keep the `British` and `British - PC` layouts and show the layout in the menu bar. If it stops working the first thing to try is just switch between them. And then if that fails I go to the `Virtual Keyboard` tab in Karabiner preferences and increment the `Country Code`. That should trigger the keyboard detection dialog. I'm up to 2 at the moment.

Comment: I removed `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` and rebooted my computer. That made Mac OS show the ISO layout (easily visible by the large Enter key) in the overview and then British-PC showed the correct layout too.

Comment: It was only after removing the file in @00schneider's answer and rebooting did i get the dialog to detect my keyboard and it suggesting iso. Once I then selected british-pc input it all worked.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have a US (ANSI) keyboard, where there is no letter key to the left of the Z.  Is that correct?  For a "normal" UK layout, you must have a European (ISO) keyboard which has this extra key.

If you do have an ISO keyboard with extra key, then you have a [keyboard type problem](https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html).

Comment: Nope, I have the ISO keyboard definitely. Because UK layout keyboard is ISO standard and the Mac also detects ISO. The only issue is the key on the left of `z` is switched with the key on the left of `1`.  

The layout of the UK keyboard :

1. the key on the left of `z` should be:`\` and `|`
2. the key on the left of `1` should be: ``` and `¬`

But mac is switched them.

Comment: @TomGewecke - I think we found a bug with a partial workaround. See my answer; though I'm still experimenting...

Comment: @xin meng Your settings screenshot is clearly NOT ISO, but ANSI. So your machine is NOT recognizing the keyboard type correctlly, if your keyboard in fact has the extra key.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. I have a QMK keyboard connected to my Mac, without correct setup, every time I type the ` (grave) key, it outputs the § (section) key. After setting it to ANSI type, I can finally type ` and ~ correctly.

Answer (score 4):

In the end, installing the Karabiner app fixed the issue.

Comment: Same here.  I could get as far as just one key not working, the backslash, however Karabiner fixed this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have configured the Keyboard settings under **Keyboard > Change Keyboard Type...** first.

Once you have configured the Mac in ISO mode the right settings should be applied, you may need to remove and add the input device (British -PC) afterwards.

Comment: What should one do if "change keyboard type" isn't there?

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: @evolutionxbox The button is on the "keyboard" tab, all the screenshots in the question are of the "input sources" tab.

Comment: I'm facing this issue again and, as @evolutionxbox, can't find that button under the Keyboard tab.

Answer (score 4):

The following [Karabiner](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements) config works for me:

[image: config]

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled Karibiner for some other reason and then remembered why I had installed it in the first place - for this issue.

However I removed the preferences files as shown above and rebooted (which may have nothing to do with the solution) and then went into the keyboard setup assistant and on to identify my keyboard.

When it asked me to press the key to the right of my left shift key I actually pressed the key to the left of the '1' key instead, and it it now generates the expected keys correctly. Haven't spotted any issues so far.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me with my Cherry KC1000 on Catalina: While connecting the keyboard, when asked about the key next to the left shift, skip the backslash key and press "Z" as if it was a regular US keyboard. On the next screen select international US ASCII keyboard. Now the British-PC layout will work as expected, along with backslash and backtick keys.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the **British - PC** keyboard layout, before clicking **Done**, press the <kbd>~</kbd>.
The picture of the keyboard will transform the "\" character into a "`" character (see pic)

[image: Screenshot of the Keyboard Settings with a British - PC keyboard layout]

Now you can click **Done**.

Comment: You are talking about pressing the key next to 1, right?  Like the answer just above yours?

Comment: It makes no sense, but after trying all the other answers it was this answer that fixed it for me. 
I removed the plist file, restarted my Mac, connected my keyboard, went through the setup assistant again, looked at my input sources - but it still showed an ANSI layout.
I then pressed the key between the `shift` and `z` keys and the layout magically changed to ISO.

Comment: @TomGewecke I think this is different - this answer is talking about pressing the key while just looking at the input sources list, not during the keyboard setup assistant.

Comment: Maybe this is a new variation of the issue in more recent versions of MacOS. I didn't try removing and re-adding the input source as suggested in another recent answer on this question, so I don't know if that would've also fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue and didn't have much luck with the approach suggested by Tetsujin. I did find however that by going into 'Keyboard -> Input Sources' and removing British - PC and re-adding it and it appeared to pick up the keyboard layout successfully. This was on Monterrey 12.6.2

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the post [< and ^ keys are swapped](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/431458) worked for me.

Essentially you have to remove the plist file, unplug the keyboard, and then redo the setup and it detects it fine.