# UK keyboard layout \ and ` swapped even with ISO keyboard and British PC layout

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

Normally to get `and \ the right way round for a British keyboard you need to change the keyboard layout to`British - PC`, *and* you need to convince MacOS that you have an ISO keyboard, rather than an ANSI one. This is described in [this *closely related but not duplicate* question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335400/how-switch-mac-uk-pc-keyboard-layout-backslash-and-backtick-to-match-normal). The solutions there have worked for me in the past (see my answer to that question).

However, I just got a new Mac, and I am now running it through a Thunderbolt 3 dock *and* a KVM switch, and that seems to have confused it somewhat.

When I run the keyboard type identifier it says they keyboard type cannot be identified:

[image]

If I click "Skip" it defaults to JIS - I *definitely* don't have a Japanese keyboard!

[image]

If I select ISO then the problem remains - @ and " are the right way round, but \ and ` are not.

How can I fix this? Note that I do have Karabiner-Elements installed, but unlike in previous versions there are no options to change the virtual keyboard type in it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I re-read [my previous answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335400/how-switch-mac-uk-pc-keyboard-layout-backslash-and-backtick-to-match-normal/390271#390271) and noticed that I needed to restart my computer when I wrote that. So I tried it, and it worked! The keyboard identification wizard appears on login but this time it had no problem identifying my keyboard as ISO.

**If you have keyboard layout issue in MacOS try restarting your computer!**