# How can I configure an external Spanish keyboard on new macOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, keyboard

Previous incarnations of macOS had detailed keyboard layout for Spanish keyboards (and other languages, of course), but since upgraded to Ventura I found only 2: Latin America and Spanish. And as you can see, they are very primitive and lacks lots of important keys

[image]

[image]

The key between Z and left shift is missing.  This problem only exists for my external Kensington keyboard, the internal one works fine.

How can I configure it correctly?

Comment: Does your hardware keyboard have an extra key between Z  and left shift?  If so, you may have a keyboard “type” problem, which has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, there is where I have the less than and greater than keys (<>), but the curious thing is that the macbook has the same layout and it works there, but the Kensington keyword dont

Comment: Anecdotally, I discovered at one time that the initial keyboard presented in the Input Sources chooser would always show as an ANSI layout, but pressing Shift would suddenly make it correctly recognise it. This wasn't repeatable in any rational way, just seemingly a one-off at first recognition of the keyboard. [This cropped up in comments under another question, but i've no hope of finding it now, sorry.]

Answer (score 0):

Those two Spanish options have been standard for some time now. They reflect the two hardware keyboards Apple makes for Spanish. To see all the keys, use the [Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/13.0/mac/13.0).

[What is the Difference Between Apple's Spanish and Latin American Keyboards](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250005126) has more info.

But it appears your machine thinks the Kensington keyboard is the US ANSI type (which does not have that extra key) instead of the European ISO type.  This kind of problem has come up here a number of times.  [How switch Mac UK PC keyboard layout backslash \ and backtick ` to match normal UK PC layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335400/how-switch-mac-uk-pc-keyboard-layout-backslash-and-backtick-to-match-normal) may be helpful.